# How to get across that a bear is not a bear is not a bear?

Tags: discussion

Many questions about bears on TGO ask merely about bears.  The OP assumes a bear is a bear is a bear.  But we all know this is not so.

The latest question about bears deals with [changing clothes after cooking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20362/how-to-deal-with-changing-clothing-which-was-used-while-cooking-as-not-to-attract) in bear country.  Possibly this is necessary for some species of bear in some places, but I very much doubt that Alaskans, for example, change clothes after cooking even in brown bear areas.  Certainly the very idea is funny for the Sierra or the Rockies.  (I change outer clothes maybe once a week.)

The OP of this question recently asked a question about [European Brown Bears](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20187/how-high-does-a-fence-need-to-be-to-prevent-european-brown-bear-to-climb-it), so I assume his latest Q is about European Brown Bears.  But we can't be expected to remember his earlier Q. And, of course, it may not be.

I'm not suggesting we VTC questions that do not specify the species (polar, brown, black, teddy), but that we edit the Q if we know, or phrase our answers to stress the distinctions.

Comment: Pretty sure questions about [teddy bears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teddy_bear) would be out of scope.

Comment: Seems unbearable. Why not grin and bear with it - or maybe ask for some clarification in a comment?

Comment: Despite there being a huge difference in how different bears react to humans, that does not mean that I treat them much different. Supposedly, in my area all you need to do is yell at the black bears from a distance and they run away scared. People say they are nothing to worry about. Some parks still require bear canisters, and I would still want bear spray in those areas, and I would still act mostly the same (though slightly less cautiously) as if I were staying near polar bears. There is a big difference, yes, but some of us still want to take precautions even with teddy bears.

Comment: To add to that, I have never had an interaction with a bear. I have heard what I thought might be a bear at night off in the darkness, but no personal interaction. And that very well might be because they run away when they hear me. But I still would be very cautious, and I recently thought the same thing as the question that you have linked to and considered keeping a tshirt with my food. You never know when they will be attracted by your smell and they accidentally come face to face with you, worse yet with a cub.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it matters, at least for this question.

If it really does you can include a link to [Do black, brown/grizzly or polar bears ever prey on humans?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/do-black-brown-grizzly-or-polar-bears-ever-prey-on-humans) or this one [What species of bear are most and least dangerous to humans?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20368/what-species-of-bear-are-most-and-least-dangerous-to-humans)